# Use sharepoint 2010 list from other sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i'm using Sharepoint 2010 and i want to create a List in a new Site, which contains Lists from the other sites.

Like a Global Overview.

Our problem is that we're using several sites with Ticketsystems. So i want to create a global list which contains all tickets from all other sites. (For sure just if they got rights to the Ticketsystem).

Is there a way to do this?

Regards

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a ticketingsystem in SP2010 with the following steps:
1. create a content type for the ticketsystem
2. add an itemreceiver to the content type
3. create a list for the ticket system
4. add contenttype binding to bind the content type to the list
5. deploy the list to the rootweb as well as all the subsites by adding the list through a webtemplate for instance

The itemreceiver you add should be an itemadding which would place a newly created ticket in the subsite also on the rootweb level. This would allow you to have all the tickets on the subsites and one allcontaining list on the rootsite level.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no generic way of mixing references from another list in a new list.

You can either integrate and copy list items from your ticket systems into a "central ticket system" or create a custom control that reads from all ticket systems and displays them in the blend you like.

There is custom development in either way.

Begin by having a look at the Data View Web Part

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-data-view-HA010099144.aspx
- http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/16/create-dataview-webpart-in-sharepoint-2010-tutorial/

There is also the Content Query Web Part

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [**SPSiteDataQuery**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) class lets you run a CAML query for all lists/libraries in a single site collection. It's pretty trivial to tie that to an SPGridView control to get a ListView-like user interface.

Internally this is what the Content Query Web Part users, so it has many of the same limitations.

Here's a reasonable [example](http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=119)